# Cannot select multiple files with FileChooser

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to implement a screen with a FileChooserListView using Kivy for an application that may require the user to select hundreds of files. The issue I am having is that I cannot select multiple input files, even though `multiselect: True`. If I use the icon view with the same configurations I am able to select multiple files, but only by clicking in each one of them individually. This is quite cumbersome for hundreds of files.

The behaviour I desire is simply to click on an initial file and then Shift+click on a final file in order to select a large number of files. Is there a way to change the behaviours that I might be missing?

My code in the .kv file containing the screen for the FileChooser:

```
ShowcaseScreen:
    name: "fc"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        FileChooserListView:
            id: list_view_tab
            multiselect: True

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: .1
            padding: 10
            spacing: 30

            Button:
                text: "Open"
                on_release:
                app.load(list_view_tab.path, list_view_tab.selection)


            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: app.go_previous_screen()
```

Comment: have you solved it after all this time?

Comment: The problem seems to be that "multiselect" only works with the filechooser icon view, the settings is ignored when you use it with the filechooser list view.